# WordPress get terms and orderby

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am querying the terms in a custom taxonomy i have with the following code:

```
<?php
  $term_slug    = get_query_var('term');
  $taxonomyName = get_query_var('taxonomy');
  $current_term = get_term_by('slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName);
  $termchildren = get_term_children($current_term->term_id, $taxonomyName);
  foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by('id', $child, $taxonomyName);
    
    echo '<li id="mid"><a href="#tab-' . $slug = $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    
  }
?>
```

This is all working great! The problem I have is that I would like to order it by menu-order or something similar. At the moment they are in random order!

Can anyone suggest what I need to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to use [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) function. Your code than would be like this (you can specifiy orderby and order arg)

```
<?php
  $term_slug     = get_query_var('term');
  $taxonomy_name = get_query_var('taxonomy');
  $current_term  = get_term_by('slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy_name);
  if ( true === is_a( $current_term, 'WP_Term' ) ) {
      $args = array(
          'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
          'orderby'  => 'id',
          'order'    => 'DESC'
      );
      $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, $args);
      if ( true === is_array( $terms ) ) {
          foreach ($terms as $term) {
              echo '<li id="mid"><a href="#tab-' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>';
          }
      }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code in the taxonomy file:

```
$wterm  = get_queried_object();
$termslug = $wterm->slug;
$termname = $wterm->name;
$termid   = $wterm->term_id;

$terms = get_terms( 'taxonomy-name', array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'child_of' => $termid
) );

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->name ;
    }
}
```